# How to place Graphviz labels to avoid edges

Tags: graphviz, dot

```
digraph {
  X -> Y [xlabel="80"]
  Y -> Z [xlabel="60"]
  Z -> X [xlabel="3"]
  Y -> X [xlabel="1"]
}
```

I render the Graphviz dot file above using:

```
dot -Tpng a.dot -o a.png
```

but find that the output image, shown below, has the edges and arrowheads overlapping with the labels.

[image]

I've tried a variety of approaches without success, and so I've reverted here to a simple example. I'm betting there's actually an obvious flag to get past this issue. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use *external* labels (`xlabel`), but standard labels (`label`).

Using standard labels in your example produces no overlapping.